Equivalent to jit.uldl in Puredata
Is there any equivalent to jit.uldl in Puredata to download a file from a url? I am aware of the shell object but failing to get that working.
Many thanks.

you can use the purest_json library to save an URL to a file:
[file /tmp/test.png,
 GET https://cdn.onemars.net/sites/perfect-fit_uk_Z61CM_JAs8/image/editor/ben-griffiths-vqeoowvzzys-unsplash_1686909408862.jpg
(
|
[purest_json/rest]

you have to know the filename beforehand, but that shouldn't be a problem.
